# How to set radio button active manually (by code)?

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2005, radio-button

I have 2 radio button say r1 and r2.grouped together and made r1 group as true from property.
I have made bool variable(vr) and attached with these radio button(DDX).

Now from code i wrote vr =1 then updatedata(TRUE). but from ui it is still showing r1 radio button active, instead of r2.
how to make radio r2 active by changing vr?

Comment: Maybe this question can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932315/why-do-my-radio-buttons-not-work

Comment: thanks for your reply.I went to link but din't find my anwswer.iwant to update radio button when variable attach to it change manually.

Comment: Please attach your code, specifically the code that has to do with r1, r2, vr, and the binding.

Answer (score 1):

`UpdateData(TRUE)` is to update the variables with the controls data. You want to update the controls from the variables, so you must use `UpdateData(FALSE)`.

Note: I always add the following defines to stdafx.h so I won't forget:

```
// to use with UpdateData
#define TOWINDOW FALSE
#define TODATA TRUE
```

and then I just use `UpdateData(TOWINDOW)` or `UpdateData(TODATA)`.